# Need to create the layout shown in pic with Bootstrap. How to place all the fields?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, responsive

I want to create this layout using Bootstrap. It should be responsive. I am unable to get things into place as I am using different rows for each image.

[image]

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/dxs2gdkg/

```html
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 content-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>State of Texas Approved</h3>
            <h2>Online Drivers Ed</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 featured-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-12 main-list">
            <ul>
                <li>America's #1 Driving School - Most Selected Course Provider</li>
                <li>Save a trip to the DPS! Official test included in the Course</li>
                <li>100% Pass Rate - Guaranteed to Pass the Official Test</li>
                <li>Mobile, Tablet or Computer - Convenient, Self-Paced Course</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="small-images">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not including any Bootstrap CSS/JS files. I updated your fiddle to include them. See your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dxs2gdkg/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'd need one row to place all content, divide it into two columns. After left column should also be a row to be divided further into two columns.

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>State of Texas Approved</h3>
                            <h2>Online Drivers Ed</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>America's #1 Driving School - Most Selected Course Provider</li>
                                <li>Save a trip to the DPS! Official test included in the Course</li>
                                <li>100% Pass Rate - Guaranteed to Pass the Official Test</li>
                                <li>Mobile, Tablet or Computer - Convenient, Self-Paced Course</li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="small-images">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
                </div>    
            </div>    
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. but how can I make the big image on the right fit into the complete column? currently it is smaller than than the column and there is space left on the right side of the image. also I need to make the height of the big image equal to the column height of the first column. big image should appear adjacent from bottom as that of the 2 small images.

Comment: It depends on how you want your img to be placed. The easiest way is to apply it as a background-image. But because of bootstrap grid uses float it won't show up until some content is in the block even with height set up in %. So the trick here is to make another div placed as a child of the right column and size in with padding-bottom like this. [link](http://codepen.io/blewherself/pen/PWavpo)

Comment: In case you want to save image as a tag `transform: scale` [like this](http://codepen.io/blewherself/pen/KaeLqa) should help. But as you can see it uglifies your picture, so better use large one instead.